# Parsing a week string to Time (YYYY-W#)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to parse a week string that an HTML5 input with a type of "week" may return, into an actual Date or Time in ruby.

An input will return a string like this: "2014-W05", where W05 is the fifth week of the year.

Here is what I tried:

```
2.1.0dev :057 > Time.strptime("2014-W05", "%Y-W%V")
2014-01-01 00:00:00 -0800
2.1.0dev :058 > Date.strptime("2014-W05", "%Y-W%V")
2014-01-01
2.1.0dev :058 > DateTime.strptime("2014-W05", "%Y-W%V")
Wed, 01 Jan 2014 00:00:00 +0000
```

As per the documentation: http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime

%V - Week number of the week-based year (01..53)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I only have the string though, I could it in two step by extracting the year and the week number from the string but I was wondering if there was way to do it directly from Date's methods

Comment: Did you try `Date.strptime("2014-W05", "%G-W%V")`? (see http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html - `%G` is the week-based year).

Comment: that worked! Add it as an answer and I'll mark it as good :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Ruby Date class (http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html), the year designator when dealing with week numbers should be the "week year", which is given by `%G`. So you would want to use:

```
Date.strptime("2014-W05", "%G-W%V")
```

So the difference is:

```
2.1.0 :004 > DateTime.strptime("2014-W05", "%G-W%V")
 => #<DateTime: 2014-01-27T00:00:00+00:00 ((2456685j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Versus:

```
2.1.0 :003 > DateTime.strptime("2014-W05", "%Y-W%V")
 => #<DateTime: 2014-01-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((2456659j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: How would you also parse the weekday, to support ISO week dates e.g. `2004-W53-6`? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date

Comment: Okay, I figured it out from the docs: `Date.strptime("2014-W1-3", "%G-W%V-%u")`