# Time.strptime doesn't parse week formatters?

Tags: ruby

Using Ruby 2.1, I am trying to find the reciprocal of `Time#strftime('%Y%U')`. For example:

```
s = Time.parse("2014-05-07 16:41:48 -0700").strftime('%Y%U')
    # 201418

t = Time.strptime(s, '%Y%U')
    # Expected: 2014-05-04 00:00:00 -0700
    # Actual:   2014-01-01 00:00:00 -0800
```

[This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446900/parsing-a-week-string-to-time-yyyy-w) suggested to use `%G` so I read the docs and tried it, but all I get out of it is the current Time. eg:

```
t = Time.strptime('201418', '%G%U')
    # 2014-05-13 12:07:51 -0700
```

From the docs, it looks to me that `%G` is only intended to work with `%V` as both are ISO 8601 and `%U` is not, but even even using `%G%V` I get back the current time.

So what's the right way to turn a `%Y%U` string into the corresponding `Time`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be a bug, since it seems to work fine if you use `DateTime` instead.

```
s = Time.parse("2014-05-07 16:41:48 -0700").strftime('%Y%U')
DateTime.strptime(s, "%Y%U")
#<DateTime: 2014-05-04T00:00:00+00:00 ((2456782j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

**Edit:**

If you look at the source code this is actually just dumb coding. `Time.strptime` calls `Date._strptime` which correctly parses out the year and week number. But then `Time.strptime` stupidly only looks for the usual year, month, day, hour, etc. and ignores the week number entirely.

I submitted a [bug report](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9836).

Comment: thanks for giving the number.. For future ref, add it to your answer.. It is valid to add there...